# Infinite Sum using $x^{-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

How can I calculate the value of the infinite sum
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^{-x}$$
By comparison to a geometric series, I know that it converges, but I don't know how to calculate an exact value. So far I have tried the following:

- I have tried to turn it into a telescoping sum, but have had no luck
- I tried adding a variable and differentiating it to create an easier sum

Any hints?

Comment: The [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).  But apparently the actual value can't be written in "closed form".

Comment: It converges so fast that its actual value, for practical purposes, is just the sum of its first five terms or so.

Comment: See also [OEIS sequence A073009](https://oeis.org/A073009).